# How to make this Google Sheet script refresh every 10 seconds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script is being used in Google Sheet to trigger a stock ticker watchlist update by using flush after it scan the table size (no. of row and column). At the moment, it can only run once per minute by using Google Sheet Time-Driven trigger. Is there a way to make it flush and update every 10 seconds to bypass the Time-Driven trigger limitation?

Appreciate anyone can help~

```
function forceRefreshSheetFormulas(sheetName) {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('*Table Name*');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var rowOffset = range.getRow();
  var colOffset = range.getColumn();

  // Change formulas then change them back to refresh it
  var originalFormulas = range.getFormulas();

  //Loop through each column and each row in the sheet
  //`row` and `col` are relative to the range, not the sheet
  var ranges = []
  var blank = []
  var original = []
  for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      if (originalFormulas[row][col] != ""){
        ranges.push( `'*Table Name*'!${columnToLetter(col + colOffset)}${row + rowOffset}` )
        blank.push('')
        original.push(`${originalFormulas[row][col]}`)
      };
    }
  };
  updateGoogleSheet(ranges,blank)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  updateGoogleSheet(ranges,original)
};
function updateGoogleSheet(ranges,values) {
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  var data = ranges.map((e, i) => ({ range: e, values: [[values[i]]] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, spreadsheetId);
}
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: You could trigger from a setInterval function using google.script.run via your browser but you would have to leave your browser on  that page as long as the exchange is open and make sure that the blank screen is disabled.

Comment: Hi Cooper, would you mind telling me where should I put that in the script is the best location? Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Anywhere in a dialog or sidebar so that it's running in the browser and not on the server. I would do it as pure javascript.

Comment: Hi Cooper, first of all, I am sorry i didn't mentioned that I am not a programmer. So there are many things that I am not familiar with when involving this kind of setting. The script is from another user here.

Would you mind helping me to optimize the code abit so it can run like every 10 seconds as a loop?

Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: I will add in here that Google Sheets has a limit on the total script runtime per account per day. Last I checked it was 6 hours (though it may have increased recently, since I saw that the cells-per-spreadsheet max just increased from 5M to 10M). But if you wanted to run a triggered script every 10 seconds around the clock, that would have to be the *only* script running on your entire account among all spreadsheets; and even at that, the runtime of each execution of the script would need to be less than 2.5 seconds. So browser-level may be your only option.

Comment: @Jacky, glad to see this post and the responses...what kind of formula do you want to refresh. I appreciate Cooper's answer...if the website accepts that refresh rate. Another way is also to use sockets if the site gives you the possibility (like for binance for example). 
I helped you refresh formulas, but now I think it's not just about formulas, but also about what kind of formula you want to refresh, and what kind of site you want to look at.